# What is the best way to create descriptive labels for tables and columns that have unique alphanumeric names?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design

I have a database of 1,050 tables with unique alphanumeric names like `B02001`, `B07009`, `B20017F`, each with columns named `B02001_001`, `B02001_002`, `B02001_003`, and so on. I'm trying to create a way to search for tables by their actual subjects and titles.

For instance if table `B07009`'s subject is `Educational Attainment` and the columns `B07009_001`, `B07009_002`, `B07009_003` are  `High School Diploma`, `Some College`, `Bachelor's Degree or Higher` and so on, how can I create a way to search the database for tables matching "education" or "profession" or "commute time" and get the columns that I need? Some of the tables have over 100 columns with names that exceed 64 bytes which is why I can't simply name the tables and columns with their descriptive names.

I've tried creating a table called `labels` but some tables have hundreds of columns (like the Professions table) and exceed the postgres row size limit of 8192 bytes. I've also considered storing the lables for every table and column in a json file and searching it with python before executing SQL statements. What is the best way to attack this problem?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum!  Do the tables have comments? There is a way of extracting the column names of all tables - you could concatenate the 1st + 2nd + 3rd to a limit of 64 chars (or 2,3,4 or ...). Best though would be to do the legwork and actually trawl through these and give the tables **meaningful descriptive** names and put in comments which go into more detail - not sure on limits to comments. Just ensure that your QA procedures are changed so as **NOT** to allow this to happen into the future!

Comment: The tables all have descriptive names in a separate file. The data are from the American Community Survey from the U.S. census department. I have a csv file with every table and column identifier matched with their descriptive names and topics.

Comment: OK - so you have a way of identifying the purpose/raision d'etre of the tables - having error messages saying that an FK of table `B02001` has been violated isn't going to tell a dev/end-user very much... If you have a way of automating at least the start of the process, great, but I think that in order to do the job properly, at least **some** manual intervention will be required - had same issue with old DOS based system migration from 16 -> 32 bit - crappy file system "db" -> RDBMS many moons ago - I would urge you to get this right - getting new devs up to speed is much easier also!!

Comment: Are there gun laws in your area?  If no, then the guy who created those table names should beware.

Comment: @RickJames blame the U.S. census department lol

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? Please don't tag for more than one!

Comment: Seriously recommend you do the legwork and give the columns meaningful names. Yes, abbreviating some to fit a 63-character limit will be needed, but that's life. NB Postgres truncates column names to 63 chars in DDL and queries -- if they will still be unique you can let Postgres do it for you.

Comment: I decided to handle it with a Python dictionary in sqlalchemy rather than renaming columns or using foreign keys.

Comment: And what happens if new IT-manager arrives and says "Right, we're switching to Clojure!" (or Scala or Kotlin or whatever s/he's read in the on-flight magazine this week!)? Data and meta-data should be kept **in the database** where it **belongs**!

Comment: You're 100% right of course. Upon reconsideration I've decided to rename the tables and columns more descriptively as per Rick James's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(MySQL...)

Consider writing a script (in, say, Perl) to go through the schema *and* all the relevant source code.  Wherever it finds "B07009", it turns it into "B07009_Educational_Attainment" and then truncates to 32 characters.

- Having the original name as part of the new name ensures uniqueness.
- 32 is messy-long, but will *usually* contain enough of the meaning.
- Going all the way to 64 is risking hitting some other limit that is not well documented or checked.  (In the Data Dictionary in 8.0, some things are "db_name/table_name", which technically needs to be limited to no less than 129, but I suspect that it, or something like it, has a bad limit.)
- If JOINs are using aliases for table names, and I hope they are, beware of this renaming applying to them.

100 columns is pretty ugly, but, in most cases, handled by MySQL.